# Getting UTF8 characters as ??? when results are fetched to application using Zend DB

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, utf-8

I am trying to fetch utf8 characterset data from mysql database but i am getting ?????? instead of utf8 data. These are the configurations in my application. I am able to view the utfdata in my php myadmin. but when it comes to application it is displaying as ????

**Application Header**

```
< meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

**Boot Strap setupDatabase:**

```
$db->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
$db->query("SET character_set_results=utf8");
$db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

**Zend Application.ini**

```
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.params.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES UTF8;"
```

**MySql Character Set**

```
character_set_client    utf8

character_set_connection    utf8

character_set_database  utf8

character_set_filesystem    binary

character_set_results   utf8

character_set_server    latin1

character_set_system    utf8

character_sets_dir  c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\share\charsets\
```

Comment: Can you show some of the code you are using to output the data?

Comment: ??.??.??????? ????? (????????) ???? 10 ?.??????????? ?.??????????????

?.??????????????
?????????

Phone:
Fax:
Email:
Website: 

"This is what all i am getting"

Comment: $users_info = new Model_DbTable_Users();

$query  = $users_info->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART)->setIntegrityCheck(false)->where("is_deleted='0'");
        $query->join(array('countries'), 'users.country = countries.id', array( 'countries.country_name'));
        $this->view->info = $users_info->fetchAll($query);

Comment: Try resources.view.charset = "utf-8" and resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8" and ensure your sourcefiles are encoded appropriate

Comment: yeah also add meta content: utf-8 header, and try htmlspecialchars with utf8 encoding

Answer (score 0):

Rob Allen has a nice tutorial UTF8, PHP and MySQL

http://akrabat.com/php/utf8-php-and-mysql/

May be it will help you. Don't forget to go through the comments also .

Hope your database and table also with the same utf-8.